# customizing android:divider, provided drawable doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to make myself a widget that shows a path using spinners, so between each spinner i want a / symbol....
Since the user changes the path all the time, its cumbersome to manage the interval views i added at first, and i wanted to give the divider parameter a shot... but it seems i can't get this working, using

```
android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
```

i get a thin grey line between the spinners, but as soon as i put in

```
android:divider="@drawable/slash"
```

there's nothing, my drawable is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="line"
            android:top="1dip" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2dip"
                android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

which i took from another post here on stackoverflow....

just to be sure, i tryed to add the drawable as a background for the linearlayout encapsulating the spinners, and i got a flat black line, so even if the rotation didn't seem to work, at least for the background, the drawable was found....

the minSdk is set to 21, so as far as i understand it, this should work?

Answer (score 0):

got it solved somehow, i am puzzled though, the slash i took from another post here (unfortunately i didn't keep the link, and i don't find it again :( ), so i supposed it should have worked.
I worked through https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html 
and to get it working i had to add inside shape

```
<size  android:width="20dip"
                android:height="20dip" />
```

i would have preferred to say 2 ems, but i couldn't its my first with drawables, so at least on my 2 devices i tested it on, those 20 dip seem ok, i hope it will be ok for every other display.... i would have preferred something linked to the character size in the spinners... so if someone knows how to do that...

then, the rotate, didn't work as above, it produced a flat line, i had to change the angles to

```
        android:fromDegrees="-45"
        android:toDegrees="-45"
```

which is IMHO not logical, and not what was in the original example, nor implied by https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

but as of now, the thing looks not nice, but functional enough, if anyone has a suggestion on how to get it nice, i am open for it ;)